# Как в Angular вывести данные из массива объектов?

Tags: angular, angular10

```
export interface AuthorModel{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    printingEdition: string[];
}
```

[image: Вывод в консоли, как раз хочу вывести printingEdition.title]

[image: Пробую вот такой код но не работает, в консоли ошибок нет]

[image: Код компонента]

Comment: `{{author.printingEdition.title}}` как-то так.. а ngFor с author.printingEdition убирайте

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ) Но к сожалению не сработало.

Comment: @InDevX Вот такая ошибка в консоли  core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at GetAuthorsComponent_div_2_Template (get-authors.component.html:5)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at refreshView (core.js:7326)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8427)
    at refreshView (core.js:7350)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7132)
    at refreshView (core.js:7376)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8427)
    at refreshView (core.js:7350)

Comment: Тогда вы ngFor не правильно построили, что ли.. Старый, тот что я говорил удалить - там `let pe of author.authorInPrintings` и вывод потом `{{author.printingEdition.title}}`

Comment: Ваш `printingEdition` это не массив строк - это объект

Comment: @AlexanderChernin То есть мне нужно создать еще модель printingEdition и сделать не массив строк а что то типа printingEdition: PrintingEditionModel[] правильно?

Comment: Для начала и по-простому можно так: `printingEdition: any;` А далее в html `{{author.printingEdition.title}}` и ngFor убрать как верно заметил @InDevX

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я сделал все как вы сказали , но все равно не работает(( удалил второй ngFor сделал printingEdition: any; и в хтмл написал {{author.printingEdition.title}}. В консоле таже ошибка что я ранее писал в коментарии

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что это поле просто не присваивается и остается неинициализированным, то есть `undefined`. Смотрите где вы его присваиваете, то есть создаете объект типа AuthorModel

Comment: @Dmitriy Если у вас authors это массив с первого скрина то сделайте как я написал выше, только там опечатался, в выводе не author а pe

Comment: @InDevX Все сработало) Огромное вам спасибо)))))

Comment: @Dmitriy Ну и у вас беспорядок с моделями какой-то, если там указан один тип, а у вас другой он, то ошибка будет падать, но этого не происходит.

Comment: @InDevX То есть должно быть не string[] а должно быть как на сервере?Или как не много не понял)

Comment: @Dmitriy В AuthorModel третий ключ не printingEdition а authorInPrintings тогда уж, а с типом вроде норм всё

Comment: @InDevX А понял) Спасибо)))